# Process Builder Update Parent (lookup) Record Field

Tags: workflow, process-builder, lookup, field-update, childrecords

*I simply want to update a field via a Lookup.*

Object Customer Master has a lookup to standard object Account (CM is a related list on the Account layouts as well).  I have a custom Lookup field on the Account.

**I want to stamp the ID of the Customer Master to the Account**.

*(there "will never be" more than one record despite the many-to-one possibility via Lookup - but EVEN IF THERE WERE, I want the CM record being touched to set it's ID into the Account custom lookup field)*

In my screenshot, note that field picklist at the bottom (red).  It is showing me fields **from the child** (Customer Master), **NOT the lookup to Account** (note above in green, I've picked what I want to update).

[image]

The verbiage is bad enough (because it calls it "record type", and on the screen where you select it, you are selecting a FIELD on the RECORD you want to update, bu the screen asks you what RECORD you want to update.

I am at a complete loss.  Nothing is making sense.

**How do you update a field on the lookup record using Process Builder?**  Every search I come up with dances around this without an actual example!  I'd actually like it if someone points out something I spent an hour missing at this point.  *Much rather have a workflow, but... (sigh)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have selected same `Customer Master object` via `Account` I mean

> `Customer Master--->Account---> Customer Master`

That's why, it is displaying Customer Master fields and not Account fields.

So, during `record type` selection select `'Account'` (**NOTE:** *without right arrow*) as follows.

Then you will get all the related fields of the Account object.

[image: Select a record to update]

After choosing, Record Type will show like: `[Customer_Master__c].Account`

Comment: "Without right arrow".     (sigh)   Yep, I needed that slap in the face.  THANK YOU.  Totally makes sense, since it kept taking me to Account and then since forced to do so, I was selecting the very field I want to update.. the lookup back to the very object being Processed.   *Wow*.   Thanks again.  I just lost two geek points...

Comment: Unfortunately, though it is clearly defined properly, it does not work.  Figures.  No errors, no nothing.  Rewrote it 3 times, now it's literally "every edit of CustMast, stick the CustMast ID onto the Account lookup field".  Nothing.  The next investigation begins.  Yay.

Comment: And... I think posting here sometimes causes your (my) brain to suddenly work.  The first step was set loooong ago to "when created".  Blah.    Thanks again.

Comment: Nice to hear that :)